# Response.WriteFile writing the webpage source instead of the text file

Tags: c#, response.write

When I am trying to get a text file from shared location and when user opens it from web browser its not showing text file content and it is showing the page source. How to avoid that? What am i doing wrong? here is my code. but when i run in my local i can able to see the text file data and i am getting page source too. My English is bad sorry if there are any mistakes.

```
 GridViewRow rw = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
 LinkButton lnkTxtFile = (LinkButton)rw.FindControl("lnkTxtFile");
 string strFilename = lnkTxtFile.Text.Replace("/","\\");
 System.IO.FileInfo targetFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(strFilename);
 Response.Clear();
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + targetFile.Name);
 Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
 Response.WriteFile(targetFile.FullName);
 HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: If you are serving up a text file, shouldn't your MIME type be `text/plain`?

Comment: Well what's the value of `targetFile.FullName`?

Comment: Did you try to set mime to text/html? Response.ContentType = "text/html"; Not sure what you're asking though :)

Comment: even i if i put "text/plain" its not working.

Comment: targetFile.FullName = "\\\\cchclu05\\public\\MetroE_Warehouse\\Salt Lake City\\Salt Lake City Shipped\\Thanksgiving Point Executives Suites\\LEHIUTCD00W.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

with

```
Response.End();
```

Comment: if i do that I am getting exception "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack." But its working. How to avoid that exception?

Comment: when i debug it its working fine i mean i can open the file but when i deployed it its not working. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Add logging to the code, and log the exception being thrown (if any). Check permissions, the paths to the downloadable files, etc

Comment: I am getting below exception. System.Web.HttpResponse.WriteFile(String filename)
   at Configs.gvConfigs_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) in C:\Users\bpucha1103c\Desktop\CellBackHaul_Publish\Configs.aspx.cs:line 59
2013-02-05 13:31:21,412 [19] WARN  System.Web.UI.Page [(null)] - Logging:System.IO.IOException: The account used is a computer account. Use your global user account or local user account to access this server.

Comment: It seems that the user account you're using in production doesn't have the permissions to access the server where you have your files. When you fix the permissions error everything will work fine. Don't forget to upvote my answer if it was helpful, and mark one of the answers as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` to `Response.End();`

I suspect that `CompleteRequest()` is rendering the rest of the page. `Response.End()` closes the response stream and returns it immediately to the client.

Comment: if i do that I am getting exception "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack." But its working. How to avoid that exception?